# Find out the Product Sold

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query regarding a table structure.We are using single SQL SERVER 2008 Database for two online selling websites.i.e.,The products which the two websites uses are same,but the description about the products are different.For example,we will sell a "Toy" of same price and model on both websites but with different description.At present I used two different id for websites say,Id "1" for Website 1 and Id as "2" for website 2.And also populated the Product table with diiferent Id's for same product along with the description and website id.
Now the problem is I need to find out how many "Toy" has been sold out in both websites together.
Can any one help me out?Should I introduce a separate table structure to relate the Productid?

Comment: Your chosen scheme requires you to instroduce a cross-reference table in order to resolve disparate toy ids to the item.  An alternative would be a webid + the same product code, such as 1 + XXX (1XXX), 2 + XXX (2XXX), etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your choices are

- minimal change to achieve your purpose
- produce a properly normalised design

A minimal change might be that table you propose

A normalised design might be

```
product
  code
  standard_description
  standard_price

website
  code
  description

website_product
  website_code
  product_code
  description
  price

order
  id
  website_code
  ...

order_line
  order_number
  line_number
  product_code
  quantity
  ...
```

That way the same product has the same code on both websites but you can have differing descriptions (and prices if necessary)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!But we have different product code for the same product on both websites.In that case should i use another table to match the two different product codes.For Ex:Website1ProductCode  Website2ProductCode Id